# Cordova camera PictureSourceType PHOTOLIBRARY v SAVEDPHOTOALBUM

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

None of this values working to launch the photo gallery in a phonegap application for android!!!

When the `getPicture` method is invoked with any of this values it does not pull up the photo gallery.

I build the app using the phonegap build cloud services

Please help,

sample code -

```
function getPhoto(source) {
  alert("getting photo");
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: source });
}
```

Comment: Can you console log source and destinationType to see what they actually are when getPhoto is called?  Also I am assuming onPhotoURISuccess and OnFail are functions defined elsewhere in the code, correct?

Comment: Yes the onPhotoURISuccess and OnFail are defined elsewhere in the code

Comment: console log source and destinationType in build??? on android phone?

Comment: Actually yes, you can access the JavaScript console for a PhoneGap running on a device.  Check out this site: http://debug.phonegap.com/.  Basically, you add a script element to your DOM and then access the console by going to a webpage.  It's pretty handy.

Comment: BTW, just a guess here: you will need to change destinationType.FILE_URI to navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI

Answer (score 8):

`Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY == entire library`

`Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM == camera photo album`

If you want users to upload any image on their phone stick to `PHOTOLIBRARY`. 
Or if you want users to upload only the pictures taken by the phone camera then use `SAVEDPHOTOALBUM`.

Comment: Where is this documented? I am using SAVEDPHOTOALBUM and I can upload anything on my Nexus 6

Comment: This link https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera has references to both options but does not clearly explain the use case. I used this in 2014, library may have changed.

Comment: I found out that on Android both options are the same.

Answer (score 0):

May be below line of codes help you out.

```
function getImage()
{
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhotoSuccess, onCapturePhotoError,{ quality: 80, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
}

function onCapturePhotoSuccess(imageURI) 
{   
    var smallImage = document.getElementById('id_for_setting_pic_somewhere_in_html');
        smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageURI;
}


function onCapturePhotoError(message) 
{
    console.log('Captured Failed because: ' + message); 
}
```